Creating a field in QField based on EXIF of photos
Is it possible to create fields that are copy of an EXIF tag of a photo in a different field?
i.g taking a photo in the field 'photo 1' and having it automatically populate the field 'photo 1 geotag' with the longtitude and latitude EXIF of this photo? (NOT based on the feature's coordinates)
